How can I use XSLT to copy Parent Segment value to Child Segment?
i am trying to write XSLT mapping copy parent value to child nodes, ContainerCode -- > Serialshippingcontianercode value we need to pass to its subnodes under new tag , i have written XSLT but it is giving empty values for that segment, not giving any values for that segment.Please help me on this..
i attached sample input and output as below. Please check.
Input:
<StandardBusinessDocument>
  <receivingAdvice>
    <LogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
        <ContainerCode>
          <serialShippingContainerCode>ContainerCode123</serialShippingContainerCode>
        </ContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <ContainmentLine number="1">
        <containedItemIdentification>
          <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>Value1</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>New1</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>Value2</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>New2</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
        </containedItemIdentification>
      </ContainmentLine>
      <ContainmentLine number="2">
        <containedItemIdentification>
          <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>Value1</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>New1</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>Value2</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>New2</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
        </containedItemIdentification>
      </ContainmentLine>
    </LogisticUnitLineItem>
    <LogisticUnitLineItem>
      <logisticUnitIdentification>
        <ContainerCode>
          <serialShippingContainerCode>ContainerCode2nd</serialShippingContainerCode>
        </ContainerCode>
      </logisticUnitIdentification>
      <ContainmentLine number="1">
        <containedItemIdentification>
          <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>686</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>SUPP</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
          <Identification>
            <IdentificationValue>789</IdentificationValue>
            <IdentificationType>SUPP1</IdentificationType>
          </Identification>
        </containedItemIdentification>
      </ContainmentLine>
    </LogisticUnitLineItem>
  </receivingAdvice>
</StandardBusinessDocument>

** Desired Output:**
<StandardBusinessDocument>
   <receivingAdvice>
      <LogisticUnitLineItem>
         <logisticUnitIdentification>
            <ContainerCode>
               <serialShippingContainerCode>ContainerCode123</serialShippingContainerCode>
            </ContainerCode>
         </logisticUnitIdentification>
         <ContainmentLine number="1">
            <containedItemIdentification>
               <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>Value1</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>New1</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>Value2</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>New2</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>ContainerCode123</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>PAL</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
            </containedItemIdentification>
         </ContainmentLine>
         <ContainmentLine number="2">
            <containedItemIdentification>
               <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>Value1</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>New1</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>Value2</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>New2</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>ContainerCode123</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>PAL</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
            </containedItemIdentification>
         </ContainmentLine>
      </LogisticUnitLineItem>
      <LogisticUnitLineItem>
         <logisticUnitIdentification>
            <ContainerCode>
               <serialShippingContainerCode>ContainerCode2nd</serialShippingContainerCode>
            </ContainerCode>
         </logisticUnitIdentification>
         <ContainmentLine number="1">
            <containedItemIdentification>
               <gtin>00000000000000</gtin>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>686</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>SUPP</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>789</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>SUPP1</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
               <Identification>
                  <IdentificationValue>ContainerCode2nd</IdentificationValue>
                  <IdentificationType>PAL</IdentificationType>
               </Identification>
            </containedItemIdentification>
         </ContainmentLine>
      </LogisticUnitLineItem>
   </receivingAdvice>
</StandardBusinessDocument>

** XSLT I used is below:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LogisticUnitLineItem">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ContainmentLine"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LogisticUnitLineItem">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Identification>
        <IdentificationValue>
          <xsl:value-of select="/serialShippingContainerCode"/>
        </IdentificationValue>
        <IdentificationType>PAL</IdentificationType>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Identification"/>
      </Identification>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Please assist here.

You could use this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  
  
  <xsl:template match="LogisticUnitLineItem">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <!-- Use a tunnel parameter to forward logisticUnitIdentification/ContainerCode/serialShippingContainerCode/text() -->
        <xsl:with-param name="serialShippingContainerCode" select="logisticUnitIdentification/ContainerCode/serialShippingContainerCode/text()" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  
  <!-- We only need to insert een extra Identification once; therefore added a predicate[last()]-->
  <xsl:template match="Identification[last()]">
    <xsl:param name="serialShippingContainerCode" tunnel="yes"/>
    <!-- Copy just the current node -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <IdentificationValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="$serialShippingContainerCode"/>
      </IdentificationValue>
      <IdentificationType>PAL</IdentificationType>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  
</xsl:stylesheet>


Thanks for your response, when i have multiple identification segments, new segment we are creating also repeating as many time,  i have updated input and output in my post, can you please check

Changed. I suggest that you use this example as a good starting point. If you have any new business rules, please ask a new question adding your changed attempt xslt.
See What should I do when someone answers my question?
